# JQuery UI Accordion - Sortable Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using this code to make the accordion sortable, and to make the active accordion panel move to the top of the stack:

```
    $(function() {
    var stop = false;
    $("#ccaccordion h3").click(function( event ) {
        if ( stop ) {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            stop = false;
        }
    });

    $("#ccaccordion").accordion({
            header: "> div > h3",
            autoHeight: false,
            change:
              function(event, ui){
                ui.newHeader.parent().prependTo(this);
              }
        }).sortable({
            axis: "y",
            handle: "h3",
            stop: function() {
                stop = true;
            }
        });

});
```

However it doesn't seem to be working. The standard demo code works fine with my html:

```
    $(function() {
        $( "#ccaccordion" ).accordion();
    });
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what's not working exactly? And could you throw up a minimal example of the problem at http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Ah that's strange it works fine on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TvV2S/

Comment: I'm using Code Igniter, and all my other scripts are working, but not this one?

Comment: Not showing any errors in the firbug console. I'm probably missing something really obvious...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorted,

I wasn't wrapping the h3 and subsequent div with another div. Knew it would be something simple. Thanks for your time Thomas! Yet again it was just me being an idiot...

Comment: Awesome. :) I didn't see any of your answers to my comment. I think you have to prefix them with @Thomas: for me to be notified.